# how to read an instance model file of DSL created using EMF and XText?

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf

I have an AADL instance file. AADL is a modelling language using XText and EMF.
I want to load that AADL instance file into my java program and access its components. How can i approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is [load a model in a standalone Java application](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xtext/FAQ#How_do_I_load_my_model_in_a_standalone_Java_application.C2.A0.3F).